# Power an arduino on a 12V circuit

Tags: power

I am doing a simple circuit with a 12V power supply to power a 12V LED strip. I'd like to be able to switch ON/OFF the strip with a relay connected to my Arduino. I'd like to know if I can power my Arduino directly from the VIN pin using 12V source. I saw that the Arduino can support up to 12V.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Product page says?

Comment: *I saw that the arduino can support up to 12V* - isn't this your answer?

Comment: Not from `Vin` pin probably. But from the power-in jack.

Comment: this question about stripleds has been asked too many times, try reading some answers to learn more about how they work , and power sensitivity from 12 to 14.2V.. see related on right side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling 7W 12-14V power LED with Arduino](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101340/controlling-7w-12-14v-power-led-with-arduino)

Comment: I just want to know how to wire my arduino to a 12V power supply, the question is not about the led part. I couldn't find a clear answer about that

Comment: So now can you update us about which part is still not clear?

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, many Arduino (and clones) are rated for supply voltage up to 12V. But note that if you use 12V power, the on-board regulator will get rather hot.  Providing decent ventilation and maybe even extra heat sink would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you can. Since there are no information about which Arduino you are using, Lets assume that you use Arduino uno. Based on the [official webpage](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) documentation, the recomended voltage input is ranging from 7 - 12 V. Therefore it is possible.